# How to view servicebus message in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using the Azure Service Bus topic mechanism. I have sent the messages to topic and want to see the messages which are all sent to the topic in azure portal.
I can see the messages count but want to see the actual messages instead of count.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Service Bus Explorer.

You can download it from here:
https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases

Here is a tutorial on how to use it:
http://colinvermander.com/tag/service-bus-explorer/

And here is a link for more information about the software and features: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available/

Comment: Need a solution for mac.

Comment: Definitely need a solution for macOS!

Comment: This doesn't really address the question about viewing in the Azure Portal, but allowing you to view in another application. Is there anyway to view in the actual Portal?

Comment: If you use mac, there is [Cerulean](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features), a cross-platform app from Cerebrata

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something, but I can not access the Service Bus Explorer on the link provided. It only redirects me to MSDN samples...

Comment: The solution I used is Chocolatey on this link https://chocolatey.org/packages/ServiceBusExplorer. Proved very useful for viewing Topic subscriptions' details since the GUI in the Portal is not very helpful regarding that.

Answer (score 2):

Most easy way get this done ::

1. https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases
2. Check the assets folder of required version.
3. Download the Zip file among others.
4. unzip to new folder and double click on "ServiceBusExplorer" (not exe.config file).

Now you can connect and see the actual messages.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has recently released Service Bus Explorer on Portal. We can send/receive/peek messages here. It's still in preview though.

[image]

Comment: Warning for those looking at this - as of Oct 2020, the web based Service Bus Explorer is still VERY broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Azure Service Bus manager online tool](https://azureservicebusman.com)

You will have to provide the connection string in order to use it

Thought it does not answer your question how to view it in the portal directly. Portal has very limited capabilities.